# Keep running a process in a Python Lambda (AWS) after returning a response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is the type of setup I want on my Lambda function for Python:

```
def my_function(data):
  ...

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  ...

  return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": json.dumps("Hello world!")
  }

  ...

  my_function(data)
```

Essentially, what I want to do is do some processing on the request body, return a response to the client, and then keep on running the Lambda to generate an image using the `my_function()` method. What is the best way to approach this using Lambda on AWS? I tried the `multiprocessing` module, but that seemed to not work at all (the background process gets terminated as soon as the response is returned).

Ideally, I would like to avoid AWS Step Functions if I can. Is there a way to do this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of if you execute code in a Lambda function or not, no code can execute in any language after returning from the method.

This sounds like the perfect use case for using [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).

Create an SQS queue and then send a message to it containing the information you need to create an image, before returning a response ([Python example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/sqs-example-sending-receiving-msgs.html)).

Another Lambda function can then pick up the SQS message by [polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html) & generate the image asynchronously.